# Why isn't IF array formula resulting in an array?

Tags: arrays, excel

I am using the following formula :

```
={IF(C6:C48="West","True","False")}
```

on this [Example Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mIDq.png)

I write the standard IF formula and then I press [Ctrl-Shift-Enter].

Shouldn't I expect as a result an array like this?

[Evaluation Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrKOT.png)

Why at the last stage of the evaluation the formula collapses to the the first value?

Comment: You have to assign the formula to cover a similarly sized range/array also, iirc.

Comment: One cell holds one value. Also you can just write: True and False without quotes.

Comment: The IF, TRUE and FALSE are redundant: `=C6:C48="West"`.

Comment: @JvdV so there is no way to store an array value in a cell, cells hold only scalar values, is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, one value per cell. You can have array formulas to work with though, but not sure what your goal is really. Maybe TEXTJOIN comes closest as in returning the outcome of an array into a single string.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this array?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if **at least one** cell in **C6** through **C48** contains "West", then use:

```
=COUNTIF($C$6:$C$48,"West")>0
```

If you want to test if **all** cells in **C6** through **C48** contains "West", then use:

```
=COUNTIF($C$6:$C$48,"West")=43
```

If you want to test if **each** cell in **C6** through **C48** contains "West", then in **K6** use:

```
=C6="West"
```

and copy downwards.

*(array formulas are not needed)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to store the array  {"False";"False";"False";"True";......;"False";"False";} in cell K6. However from what I am getting this is impossible because cells can contain only scalar values. Is that correct? Is there any workaround to store arrays in a cell in Excel?

Comment: Why do you want to store them? If you need them for further processing in another formula, then embed the formula that led to the array into the other formula. Or use a named range to store the array.